# Display text based on a selected option in Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

The option to select the country is through

```
<%= f.select :country_id, options_for_select(Country.all.order(:name).map{ |c| [t(c.code2.to_sym, :scope => :countries), c.id] }, selected: @customer.try(:country).try(:id)), wrapper_html: {:class=>'form-control', id:"country_name"} %>
```

And I have a text field to enter the country telephone code through this

```
<%= f.text_field :phone_country, :class=>"form-control", wrapper_html: {id: "telephone_code"} %>
```

I want the telephone code to be entered automatically based on the country selected in the previous option. I have the country codes in the database and I also understand I have to use jQuery function, but couldn't get further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".country_id").on('change', function(){
 $('.phone_country').val($(this).val());
});
```

The above function will be called when we change value of dropdown.

```
<%= f.select :country_id, options_for_select(Country.all.order(:name).map{ |c| [t(c.code2.to_sym, :scope => :countries), c.id] }, selected: @customer.try(:country).try(:id)), wrapper_html: {:class=>'form-control country_id', id:"country_name"} %>

<%= f.text_field :phone_country, :class=>"form-control phone_country", wrapper_html: {id: "telephone_code"} %>
```

Update: I tried to do a Ajax request with the following code. But still couldn't figure out how to insert data based on the drop-down.

```
  $('.country-id').on 'change', (e) ->
    $.ajax
      type: 'GET'
      url: '/new'
      data: 'country-id'
      success: (data) ->
        alert data
        return
```

Comment: Thanks. But `this` inserts the country ID whereas I want to insert the corresponding telephone code of the `country_id`.

Comment: you have to do ajax request and according to that you have to set phone_country text field value

Comment: I am sorry, I did a Ajax request but still wasn't able to change the phone_country. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry to have included the update in your answer. I thought I was updating my post, but mistakenly edited yours. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I got it. I added `data` attribute to the `options` tag of countries list and accessed that data from jQuery through `$(this).find(":selected").data("_dataname_")`.